# How to update ruby gems on ubuntu to 1.9?

Tags: rubygems

I am trying to install Shapado on a 32bit Ubuntu EC2 AMI, and updated ruby to 1.9.2 as apart of the install.  However, I get this error

```
ubuntu@domU....:/var/rails/shapado$ sudo rake gems:install
rake aborted!
Gemfile syntax error:
/var/rails/shapado/Gemfile:87: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting kEND
gem 'sass-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/sas...
                    ^
/var/rails/shapado/Gemfile:87: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting kEND
...hub.com/rails/sass-rails.git', branch: '3-2-stable'
                          ^
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:35:in `eval_gemfile'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:7:in `evaluate'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:18:in `build'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:144:in `definition'
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.2.3/lib/bundler.rb:112:in `setup'
/var/rails/shapado/config/boot.rb:8
/var/rails/shapado/config/application.rb:1
enter code here
```

Not being a ruby user, I am guessing it's to do with the gems/1.8 but if I attempt to update using

```
gem update --system
```

I get a warning that this update system is disabled on Debian.

```
ubuntu@domU-12-31-38-04-9E-D2:/var/rails/shapado$ gem update --system
ERROR:  gem update --system is disabled on Debian, because it will overwrite the
content of the rubygems Debian package, and might break your Debian system in s
ubtle ways. The Debian-supported way to update rubygems is through apt-get, usin
g Debian official repositories.
If you really know what you are doing, you can still update rubygems by setting 
the REALLY_GEM_UPDATE_SYSTEM environment variable, but please remember that this
is completely unsupported by Debian.
```

So, is this an error with having 1.8 gems, and if so, what's the best way to update this?  I can nuke the whole thing and start again if it is better that way.  I figure I should have specified a particular version instead of just following the installation instructions http://shapado.com/questions/how-to-install-shapado-on-amazon-ec2

Comment: I got that when I was running Ruby < 1.9... Are you sure you're actually switched over to Ruby 1.9.2? Can you try typing ruby -v and see what you get back?

Comment: Hmm.  I explicitly installed ruby 1.9.2 but yes, I see 1.8.7 when I tried that :(   Time to nuke and try again.

Comment: Even after sudo update-alternatives --config ruby, and then gem, with ruby -v giving me ruby1.9.3 the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

This is disabled in Debian by design.

```
gem update --system
```

Instead use this:

```
apt-get install rubygems
```

If you are still having issues, recommend you uninstall RubyGems by using Aptitude and reinstall from source. RubyGems website gives instructions [here](http://help.rubygems.org/kb/rubygems/rubygems-upgrade-issues).